# Should we delete the "data" tag?

Tags: discussion

Should we delete [data](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data)?  It doesn't seem to add value, what would even be the wiki and description for the tag, and for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data is empty.  For appropriate uses, we have [calldata](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calldata).

For clarity: making [data](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data) a synonym for [calldata](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calldata) is not helpful because that will probably lead to many questions incorrectly being tagged with [calldata](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calldata).  [calldata](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calldata) is specific and is not about analytics, oracles, historical prices, and whatever other data people are interested in...

Comment: Maybe data should just be synonym / merged with calldata. Deletion might be _overshooting the target_. :-)

Comment: @5chdn a lot of [tag:data] doesn't fit [tag:calldata].  What cases could we be concerned about? :)

Comment: Then we need a replacement tag. storage?

Comment: _Yeah, that didn't help anyone. I have removed it._ [:-P](http://meta.bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/339/6441)

Comment: _'Trivial answer converted to comment'_ wtf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, that didn't help anyone. I have removed it.

Answer (score 2):

It's not completely off the scale because `data` is a special keyword of the transaction object.

http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/units-and-global-variables.html?highlight=msg.value#block-and-transaction-properties

Comment: [tag:calldata] is exactly for this purpose.  "msg.data (bytes): complete calldata"

Comment: As I said before, If there is no other fir than calldata, make it a synonym. If there is, leave the tag with a proper description.

Comment: @5chdn What do you think the description for "data" tag should be?